# Iam not quite sure how to define Users in this case

Tags: python-3.x, pymol

iam a total noob in python; i have a background in chemistry and iam doing my master in computational chemistry. Iam trying to learn computer science as fast as i can.
I currently dont know how to solve this error. I have googled the question but the answers dont actually satisfy.
I would really appreciate if you guys give me hints on how to fix this error.
Thanks,
Thanh Le

In order for the program to work, it uses codes from this file containing:

from RunRMSD import RunRMSD
RunRMSD()

from SumRMSD import SumRMSD
SumRMSD()

then it uses codes from a file (RunRMSD) containing:

## run calcRMSD.py to get raw output from pymol

def RunRMSD():

```
# get output directory from a threefiles.txt
with open('./threefiles.txt') as fi:
    fline = fi.readline()
    flist = fline.split('\t')
    path_output = flist[1]

import os
command = '/opt/local/bin/pymol -cqr '+'./CalcRMSD.py > '/Users/thanhle/Desktop/output/'RMSD.out'
os.system(command)
```

Not sure if my path is correct though.

```
thanhs-MacBook-Pro-2:untitled folder thanhle$ python Director_RMSD.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Director_RMSD.py", line 5, in <module>
    RunRMSD()
  File "/Users/thanhle/Desktop/ftdock-2-dev2/untitled folder/RunRMSD.py", line 11, in RunRMSD
    command = '/opt/local/bin/pymol -cqr '+'./CalcRMSD.py > '/Users/thanhle/Desktop/output/'RMSD.out'
NameError: global name 'Users' is not defined
```

Comment: Add the relevant code

Comment: I just edited the code.

Comment: You have a typo,, if you want a single string just `command = '/opt/local/bin/pymol -cqr ./CalcRMSD.py > /Users/thanhle/Desktop/output/RMSD.out'`, I would also recommend using subprcess and piping to a file object

Comment: you should use `"` , as `"` escapes `'`.

Answer (score 0):

The "command" variable is not well written:

```
command = '/opt/local/bin/pymol -cqr '+'./CalcRMSD.py > '/Users/thanhle/Desktop/output/'RMSD.out'
```

The error is thrown because the path `/Users/thanhle/Desktop/output/` is not concatenated and also you are missing a apostrophe. If you don't want to parse any variable to the command it should be written:

```
command = '/opt/local/bin/pymol -cqr ./CalcRMSD.py > /Users/thanhle/Desktop/output/RMSD.out'
```